# Healthcheck for MongoDB in Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-query, dockerfile, health-check

I am trying to create a Healthcheck for my MongoDB container configured in my [Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBZJN.jpg):

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' > tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb

RUN mkdir -p /data/db

EXPOSE 27017

**HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD /etc/init.d/mongodb status || exit 1**

CMD ["usr/bin/mongod", "--smallfiles"]
```

But when I build the image and run a container, after running `docker ps` it shows `Up 20 seconds (unhealthy)` in the `status` column.

Going into the container with bash, when I try running `service mongodb start` it fails.

In the log file (`/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`) it says `Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use`

But there is no other container with MongoDB running.

What could be causing this?

Comment: How are you running your container? Can you include your `docker run` command?

Comment: Also, have you considered using the official MongoDB docker images from dockerhub? https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Comment: Docker run -d -p 2717:27017 --name example  my-mongo-app. Also I can't connect to the app through http (http://localhost:2717) like I would be able to on a working db, I imagine that's part of the same problem

Comment: Commands like `service` and `/etc/init.d` scripts don't really work in Docker.  They're also not what you really want here; definitionally, if the container is running, the `mongod` process is too, but it's not necessarily accepting connections.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a mistake on last line

Change this line `CMD ["usr/bin/mongod", "--smallfiles"]`

to

`CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--smallfiles"]`

**Update1**:

change this line
`**HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD /etc/init.d/mongodb status || exit 1**`

to

`HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD /etc/init.d/mongodb status || exit 1`

Comment: now going into the container itself it doesnt let me write any commands. it just gets stuck in the CLI.  "docker exec -it example bash"

Comment: maybe it has to do with the order of my commands in my dockerfile...like expose should be a line lower or something like that